# Is there a way to define a global validation rule on Sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

From the `sails.js` documentation:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations

it is shown that I can define a rule (via the `types` attribute) on top of a Model (the examples in the docs is `User.js` at the end).

My question is: how to do it globally? So that I can use that validation rule for *all* my models, instead of having to redefine it locally.

Thanks much.

Comment: You can't do it with types attribute... But you could make global policy which checks req.params before hitting controller.